# Ajax Post to Controller Action Cross domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I have a form on "website A" which posts to "website B".  Code included Below.

I can't get a success or a return message from my destination domain.

Any suggestions? what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").bind("click", function(){

        //turn form into json
        var formData = $("#digForm").serializeObject();
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(formData);


        alert(jsonData);

        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: jsonData,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert(errorThrown);
                            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string submission)
{
    SubmissionModel model = new SubmissionModel();

    //validate everything we need is here
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    // get json data from url
    var json =  submission;
    var submissionData = serializer.Deserialize<SubmissionModel>(json);

    model.SiteID = submissionData.SiteID;
    model.FirstName = submissionData.FirstName;
    model.LastName = submissionData.LastName;
    model.Email = submissionData.Email;
    model.Comments = submissionData.Comments;
    model.Like = submissionData.Like;
    model.Dislike = submissionData.Dislike;
    model.SubmitDate = DateTime.Now;
    db.Submissions.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    data: {submission: jsonData},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using json but for cross browser ajax posts you should be using jsonp

http://forums.asp.net/t/1780255.aspx/1

Comment: No he has not to use jsonp, you can send data with json aswell

Comment: @Mariusz, please elaborate. If I'm missing something I would like to understand better. DaveA's answer seems wrong considering process flow.

Comment: You can send json in CORS by enabling your server to accept requests with OPTIONS header [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0)

Comment: @AnthonyShwartz I'm still having issues with this, do you have a code example you could elaborate on?

Comment: @BrentonPierce, show me what you've tried so far... add code to your post

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems in the past.

With the risk of teaching grandma to suck eggs....

**First, regarding the diagnosis of the problem**
I am pretty sure this IS a same-origin-policy problem, because these result is not getting a success or error message, which is very typical.
What you **COULD** to in order to diagnose it, is to use firebug on firefox, and look at the http requests/responses themselves. Over there you **WILL** see the response, because this is before it is being filtered out by the browser.

**Regarding the solution.**

Like Anthony said, you **CAN** use jsonp. JsonP is actually a hack that works around the same-origin-policy by hiding the data as if it was a JS function.

I usually use getJson instead of ajax() for that.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

And I set it to use jsonp manually, by adding "callback=AnyName" to the post parameters.

Also, I cannot see your server B's response code, but the json data needs to be encapsulated with AnyName();  so if your json data is {json, data}, your response should be AnyName({json,data});

Comment: How do you add the callback?